# website developed in kohana working in live but only home page working in localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana

I have a website which is developed in kohana. The website is working fine in live. I have made a local copy in my localhost, Only home page is working in  local. All other pages are showing following error

Not Found

The requested URL /demo/search-ad/search-detail.html was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80

I put all file in a folder demo and my .htaccess file is changed as follows

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /demo

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|system) - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your local machine?

Comment: In bootstrap.php you set correct the 'base_url' key?

Answer (score 0):

In your **httpd.conf** file(probably in /etc/httpd2/conf/), change

`AllowOverride None`

to

`AllowOverride All`